error: static AddressSanitizer runtime is not supported on darwin
I often use -fsanitize=address when building using clang++ for getting the line number of issues, but on 9/18/2024, Apple had me agree to a new terms of service or something via the command line, and along with that, something must have changed because now I'm getting this error if I try to run with -fsanitize=address:
clang++: error: static AddressSanitizer runtime is not supported on darwin
Anyone know how I can find out what new reason is causing this? Everything I can find online refers to older problems. Thanks!
clang version:
Apple clang version 16.0.0 (clang-1600.0.26.3)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

MacOS version:
14.6.1 (23G93)
